# Uploading images to web servers

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I am in a massive rush and have to decide on a phone platform for tomorrow. Please forgive my lack of research on my own part, I just don't have the time, and would appreciate one of you geniuses to answer my question.

I need to develop an application which will take a picture and upload it to a webserver. Can this be done on a Windows 7 Phone device?

I am a windows .NET developer.

In the past on the older blackberries we had major issues with finding the latest picture taken. So basically my question is, can I build an app with a button to take a picture, and it just works out the box and uploads it without any fuss.

I really have not had the time to research the windows 7 phone API's, and this is urgent.

Thank you so much, I know people who don't research themselves should be shot, but I just don't have the time.

Thank you again.

Comment: Can a WP7 phone take a picture and upload it to a web server???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to develop an application which will take a picture and upload it to a webserver. Can this be done on a Windows 7 Phone device?

Yes.

If all you want is to be able to take a photo and not access the camera directly, you can use the [CameraCaptureTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394006%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which has been around since the beginning. This is much simpler and all of the photo taking functionality is taking care by the built in photo application. The result is just a stream to the photo. Given from your description these seems like the answer for you.

Another option starting in Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango) gives you much more direct access to the camera. Details / sample [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202956%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). This is if you want to really make your own camera application from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, offcourse. .Net is providing built-in classes to interact with the camera, take picture and then you can convert image to byte, and then you have to use a webservice (WCF is recommended usually), whihc will have interact with the database and save the picture in byte form in database. Database which will be used will be Microsoft SQL Server 2005/2008.

This might help you :
[Communication of Windows phone and WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg598947)